# How to cast the size_t to double or int C++

Tags: c++, casting, double, size-t

My question is that

I have a size_t data, but now I want to convert it to double or int.

If I do something like

```
 size_t data = 99999999;
 int convertdata = data;
```

the compiler will report warning. because it maybe overflow.

Do you have some method like the boost or some other method to do the convert?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

A cast, [as Blaz Bratanic suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184461/827263):

```
size_t data = 99999999;
int convertdata = static_cast<int>(data);
```

is likely to silence the warning (though in principle a compiler can warn about anything it likes, even if there's a cast).

But it doesn't solve the problem that the warning was telling you about, namely that a conversion from `size_t` to `int` really could overflow.

If at all possible, design your program so you don't *need* to convert a `size_t` value to `int`. Just store it in a `size_t` variable (as you've already done) and use that.

Converting to `double` will not cause an overflow, but it could result in a loss of precision for a very large `size_t` value. Again, it doesn't make a lot of sense to convert a `size_t` to a `double`; you're still better off keeping the value in a `size_t` variable.

([R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184657/827263) has some suggestions if you can't avoid the cast, such as throwing an exception on overflow.)

Comment: I recently ran into a trouble where a function that returned double was meant to return npos when it failed, but when i checked (==) the result of the function against npos it didn't return true when it should.
Checking on the console i discovered that the double casted npos was 1 integer higher than the non casted npos (size_t)

Comment: @Coyoteazul: That's a poorly designed function. Even worse, it's likely to "work" on a 32-bit system.

Comment: yup. I actually thought double had a bigger capacity than size_t, so i didn't think that casting npos would be a trouble. I commented it in case someone runs into the ame trouble

Comment: @Coyoteazul: On many modern system, `double` and `size_t` are both 64 bits. For `size_t` they're all value bits. `double` devotes a bit to the sign and several more to the exponent. `double` can easily hold a number with the magnitude of `npos` (`SIZE_MAX`), but it can't store its full precision.

Answer (score 28):

If your code is prepared to deal with overflow errors, you can throw an exception if `data` is too large.

```
size_t data = 99999999;
if ( data > INT_MAX )
{
   throw std::overflow_error("data is larger than INT_MAX");
}
int convertData = static_cast<int>(data);
```

Comment: Useful reply. I filed an edit to add this content into the end of the accepted answer so that future readers see a complete response in one place.

Answer (score 20):

Static cast:

```
static_cast<int>(data);
```

Comment: is it possible to cause the overflow, because the range of size_t is large than the range of int.

Comment: @user2701639 Well, what do you want to happen in that scenario?

Comment: @user2701639 _is it possible to cause the overflow ..._ Not with `double`.

Comment: As written, yes, this will cause an overflow if `data` is larger than the value that fits in `int` - and as such, could cause "interesting" issue, such as a negative value in `convertdata`, and when something you consider a size is negative, you know something is horribly wrong. Also, selected values of `data` may cause the value in `convertdata` to be zero, other values may represent the size as a very small positive number, although the original size is huge.

Answer (score 13):

You can use Boost [`numeric_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html#boost_numericconversion.improved_numeric_cast__.numeric_cast).

This throws an exception if the source value is out of range of the destination type, but it doesn't detect loss of precision when converting to `double`.

Whatever function you use, though, you should decide what you want to happen in the case where the value in the `size_t` is greater than `INT_MAX`. If you want to detect it use `numeric_cast` or write your own code to check. If you somehow know that it cannot possibly happen then you could use `static_cast` to suppress the warning without the cost of a runtime check, but in most cases the cost doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: that exactly what needs if you can't avoid such cast, but want program to let you know if out_of_range happens.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the program cannot be redesigned to avoid the cast (ref. [Keith Thomson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184543/5944782)):

To cast from size_t to int you need to ensure that the size_t does not exceed the maximum value of the int. This can be done using [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

```
int SizeTToInt(size_t data)
{
    if (data > std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        throw std::exception("Invalid cast.");
    return std::static_cast<int>(data);
}
```

If you need to cast from size_t to double, and you need to ensure that you don't lose precision, I think you can use a narrow cast (ref. Stroustrup: The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition):

```
template<class Target, class Source>
Target NarrowCast(Source v)
{
    auto r = static_cast<Target>(v);
    if (static_cast<Source>(r) != v)
        throw RuntimeError("Narrow cast failed.");
    return r;
}
```

I tested using the narrow cast for size_t-to-double conversions by inspecting the limits of the maximum integers floating-point-representable integers (code uses googletest):

```
EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<size_t>(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() - 2 })), size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() - 2 });
EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<size_t>(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() - 1 })), size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() - 1 });
EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<size_t>(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() })), size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() });
EXPECT_THROW(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 1 }), std::exception);
EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<size_t>(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 2 })), size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 2 });
EXPECT_THROW(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 3 }), std::exception);
EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<size_t>(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 4 })), size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 4 });
EXPECT_THROW(NarrowCast<double>(size_t{ IntegerRepresentableBoundary() + 5 }), std::exception);
```

where

```
constexpr size_t IntegerRepresentableBoundary()
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::radix == 2, "Method only valid for binary floating point format.");
    return size_t{2} << (std::numeric_limits<double>::digits - 1);
}
```

That is, if N is the number of digits in the mantissa, for doubles smaller than or equal to 2^N, integers can be exactly represented. For doubles between 2^N and 2^(N+1), every other integer can be exactly represented. For doubles between 2^(N+1) and 2^(N+2) every fourth integer can be exactly represented, and so on.