# Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error that says "implicit conversion loses integer precision" any suggestions on why it's happening on the line

```
    maxLen = strlen(line);
```

Here's the code:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <time.h>

    // Accepts: command line input
    // Returns: 0 if no error

    int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
        int x = 0, i, lCount = 0, maxLen = 0;
        char line[500], *temp;

        FILE *file = fopen("playlist.txt", "r" );

        //  check if file exists
        if (file == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open file\n");
            return 1;
        }

        /* The following code identifies each line in the text and lines are shuffled accordingly */

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
        {
            lCount++;
            if (strlen(line) > maxLen)
                maxLen = strlen(line);
        }

        rewind(file);
        char *lArray[lCount];

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
        {
            lArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line));

            if (lArray[x] == NULL){
                printf("A memory error occurred.\n");
                return(1);
            }

            strcpy(lArray[x], line);

            /* change \n to \0 */
            lArray[x][strlen(lArray[x])-1] = '\0';
            x++;
        }

        printf("Your playlist %s has %d lines with %d characters\n", argv[1], lCount, maxLen);

        printf("The original inputted array is:\n");

        for (x = 0; x < lCount; x++)
            printf("%2d %s\n", x, lArray[x]);
        /*  The array will now be shuffled: */

        srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL));

        for (x = lCount - 1; x >= 0; x--){
            i = (int) rand() % lCount;
            temp = lArray[x];
            lArray[x] = lArray[i];
            lArray[i] = temp;
        }

        printf("\nShuffled Array\n");

        for (x = 0; x < lCount; x++)
            printf("%2d %s\n", x, lArray[x]);

        /* Memory will now be freed */
          /* for (x = 0; x < lCount; x++)
            free(lArray[x]);
        strdup(lArray);
        fclose(file); */
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is a mess! Format & indent your code!

Comment: Please read how to provide [mcve]. Most of your code is completely irrelevant to the question and wastes everybodys time.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer.

For more information, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184543/248756

Comment: `size_t` is not just "equivalent", but it **is** an unsigned integer. If you have `unsigned int` in mind: _That_ is wrong! And the second sentence is wrong, too. A positive `int` can be represented in an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` and `int` represent different ranges.

`size_t`, the result type of the `sizeof` operator, can express any index of an array.  `int` may not have that range, or rarely, it may excessively encode that range.  `strlen()` returns `size_t`,  It is the best type, that is not excessively wide, to sufficiently represent all legal results.  It is an unsigned integer type.  (Not necessarily the type `unsigned`.)

So if `SIZE_MAX > INT_MAX`, as it appears to be on OP's platform, some lost of information can be lost when converting from `size_t` to `int` - hence the warning.

```
#include <string.h>
// size_t strlen(const char *s);

int maxLen;
maxLen = strlen(line);  // warning
```

Better to use

```
size_t maxLen = strlen(line);
...
//                           note prefix ---v
printf("Your playlist %s has %d lines with %zu characters\n",
   argv[1], lCount, maxLen);
```

---

BTW your have at least 2 more problems

```
       // insufficient space 
       // lArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line));
       lArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
       ...
       strcpy(lArray[x], line);

       // Following is a hacker's delight as strlen(lArray[x]) may return 0
       /* change \n to \0 */
       // lArray[x][strlen(lArray[x])-1] = '\0';

       // Instead simplest to lop \n from `line`
       while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
         line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```