# How to solve the Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' warning?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am stuck with a warning on xcode, when I try to use the function of the tesseract package:

```
ocr->SetImage(im.data, im.cols, im.rows, 3, im.step);
```

I get a warning:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you be more precise - is this an error or a warning?

Comment: It is a warning

Comment: That is a warning, not an error.  And clearly you are passing an unsigned 32bit/64bit value where a signed 32bit value is expected, hence the potential loss of precision. Which input value is the `size_t` and which parameter is the `int`?

Comment: Just add a `static_cast<int>(im.data)` (assuming it's `im.data` that's the 'offending' `size_t` argument).

Comment: thanks guys static_cast<int>(im.data) worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

References: [Implicit conversion](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/), [What is size_t?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/size_t-data-type-c-language/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184403/how-to-cast-the-size-t-to-double-or-int-c).

As documentation says:

> Implicit conversions are automatically performed when a value is
>   copied to a compatible type.

In your case, trying *int* to *size_t* is also an implicit conversion. The reason why the warning mentions about the precision:

- *size_t* is always able to store more numbers than *int*.
- While *size_t* holds always a positive value, *int* can hold also negatives.

According to these two differences between *size_t* and *int*, program assumes that some problems or precision loses can occur in the future.

In your case, you can simply convert your size_t type using [static_cast conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

```
static_cast<int>(your_size_t_type_parameter)
```

**Note**: Using this method can eliminate your warning but this can cause some loses. For example if your size_t value is very huge.